# How to replace two forEach() loops into Java Stream?

Tags: java

Any suggestion if I can replace two `forEach()` loops into Java Stream in below code?

Note: challenge for me is if any item with similar key exists in `firstConjCpnHistMap`, then I don't want to replace it, i.e. I want to skip that iteration... which means this question does have 2 questions:

1. How to avoid two `forEach()` loops
2. Is there any way while putting key/value in `Map`, if the similar key exists then **DON'T** replace it, contrary to behavior of `HashMap` i.e. replacing whenever put operation occurs.

```
public List<TicketingDocumentServiceCouponHistory> build(GetTicketingDocumentRS rs) {
    LOGGER.debug("Building FirstConjCpnHistList for TKTRES - 137");

    Map<BigInteger, TicketingDocumentServiceCouponHistory> firstConjCpnHistMap = new HashMap<>();

    rs.getDetails()
        .get(0)
        .getTicket()
        .getHistory()
        .forEach(history -> history.getServiceCouponHistory()
            .forEach(couponHistory -> {
                if (couponHistory.getCoupon().intValue() % 4 == 1 &&
                    !couponHistory.getCoupon().equals(BigInteger.ONE) &&
                    !firstConjCpnHistMap.containsKey(couponHistory.getCoupon())) {
                    firstConjCpnHistMap.put(couponHistory.getCoupon(), couponHistory);
                }
            }));

    return new ArrayList<>(firstConjCpnHistMap.values());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Stream.flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)
2. use [Map.putIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-)

```java
 rs.getDetails()
    .get(0)
    .getTicket()
    .getHistory()
    .flatMap(history->history.getServiceCouponHistory().stream())
    .forEach(couponHistory -> {
        if (couponHistory.getCoupon().intValue() % 4 == 1 &&
            !couponHistory.getCoupon().equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            firstConjCpnHistMap.putIfAbsent(couponHistory.getCoupon(), couponHistory);
        }
        });
```